# webpage caused internet explorer to close and reopen

Tags: internet-explorer

I have simple file upload input on page.

input type="file"

When ever i click on that, page get reload with the message "A problem with this webpage caused internet explorer to close and reopen".

I already removed all add-ons. Updated browser version to 11. But no luck.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the page?

Comment: @Slace Its occurs on all sites. Even I try to upload photo on facebook.com, then also its behave same way.